# Required code signature missing for a library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I am using Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8 and facing this error when running my app. I have used third party library [SlideMenuController](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift).

When I run my app I encounter this error again and again but didn't found any solution.

Deleting derived data works some time but not always.

> /Users/amsyt014/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8615687B-36F4-4367-9289-C265F3DABDD5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4794E2EF-863E-4836-A8E7-5A0F0ABA52E0/Shopaves.app/Frameworks/SlideMenuControllerSwift.framework/SlideMenuControllerSwift:
>   required code signature missing for
>   '/Users/amsyt014/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8615687B-36F4-4367-9289-C265F3DABDD5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4794E2EF-863E-4836-A8E7-5A0F0ABA52E0/Shopaves.app/Frameworks/SlideMenuControllerSwift.framework/SlideMenuControllerSwift'

Answer (score 25):

The following command in the Podfile helped me:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

Comment: Fantastic solution if cleaning derived data doesn't work!

Comment: Clearing derived data didn't help. This one did! Thanks for sharing this. 

Comment: This works perfectly. Deleting Derived Data and Clean Project didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 24):

**Method 1**

Add following code to your pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

**Method 2**

Perform following steps

1. Delete application from mobile or simulator (wherever you are facing this issue).
2. Select slideMenuController.framework in project navigator,  right click on it, an click show in Finder. Open _CodeSignature folder and delete all files except CodeResources.
3. Close Xcode, open Terminal and enter the following command

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   ```

   This will remove all derived data from xcode.
4. Open XCode, clean and run application. Hopefully, problem will be resolved.

Comment: what does the script in Method 2 does, internally. Just disalbe and code signing, i guess?

Answer (score 12):

I had same issue with my mac10.12.5 & Xcode 9, 
There seems to be issue with existing data at derived data location SO better just remove your derived data  either by :

```
XCode>Prefrences>Locations>click on arrow at Derived Data location & delete it.
```

or either by writing this command on terminal: Make sure your xcode is in application or you mention your xcode location :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Now Open XCode, run application. Hopefully, problem will be resolved.
Good luck...

Comment: It worked for me. I was getting code signing required: RoundedSwitch.framework.
I did the same but please remember to close simulator & Xcode before deleting that DerivedData Folder.

Answer (score 6):

I am using the same library. Here is what I did to resolve the issue.

Find the SlideMenuControllerSwift.framework in your project folder/pods folder in xCode. Go to its location in finder.

Inside the framework you will find _CodeSignature folder. I had around 5 files in that _CodeSignature folder. Delete all except Code Resources file.

Clean build project and run.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. For FYI, previously it was working me deleting POD file for SlideMenuControllerSwift. Steps I were following :

1. Comment out SlideMenuControllerSwift POD name and install pod again.
2. Clean build.
3. Again uncomment SlideMenuControllerSwift POD name and install pod again. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I am experiencing the same issue with Xcode Version 8.0, having turned on the 'automatically manage signing' feature.

Other solution is:

Please see this issue: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/1401

Second solution may be work for you.

**Note: Please remove derive data from here `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`**

Comment: issues in Xcode 8.0 don't seem to go even tried this but no use :(

Answer (score 3):

I've solved my issue with setting "ENABLE_BITCODE" to 0

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this resolved my issue as well

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by setting a profile underneath Build Setting-->Code Signing Identity in my Framework project. My embedded Framework (the other framework within my own framework) is added to the Copy Files section in Build Phase.

hth!

Answer (score 1):

Solved just by deleting the derived data and the app on the device. If that doesn't work try to toggle on/off the automatic signing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when creating my own framework and update it by `Pods`.

I **turn off** `Automatically manage signing` and now it works good.

Hope it help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the correct Xcode version you're currently running in Xcode preference / Locations.

[image: Please refer this image for your reference]