# Project wont run on simulator in xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode

After upgrading to xcode8, my project will no longer run on the simulator (runs on a device)

Error:

```
  /Users/johnsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JT-fnslglvifmonzwhlgrchcqujqiwt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/
Assets.bundle: Is a directory

    Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have deleted the entire deriveddata folder and cleaned the project several times with no success. Any ideas how to fix please?

Comment: Try running on release build. Are you using Cocoapods?

Comment: @Windindi I am using Cocoapods

Comment: Are you getting this error for any particular pod?

Comment: How would I know which pod the error relates to?

Comment: It should have mentioned that pod in the error but if it is not then I don't think it is the same issue that I faced with pods and simulator code signing. Are you automatic / manual code signing option?

Comment: What issue did u face and how did you fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40169679/1966728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CocoaPods (especially an older version), you'll notice that all the resource bundle targets in the pods project file don't have an info.plist.
Set them all using CocoaPods generic Info.plist and it'll run.
This however is not a permanent solution. It will reset on next `pod install`

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66538

**EDIT:**
If you don't happen to have a generic plist file in your project already
create a new file `Info.plist` in Pods `Target Support Files/Pods-<App Name>/` and paste this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>org.cocoapods.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>BNDL</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.0.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}</string>
  <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
  <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**EDIT 2:**
Fixed the values above. Apple won't accept it when uploading to App Store the way it previously was.
It shouldn't have `CFBundleExecutable`
and the `CFBundlePackageType` should be set to `BNDL`

Comment: There is no generic plist

Comment: Pods / Targets Supporting Files / Pods / Info.plist.

When setting the .plist via the Xcode project editor, the generic pod info.plist will be towards the bottom.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue as you @RunLoop. There isn't a generic plist file. Editing my answer now