# Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status. I am using Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xcode9, ibdesignable

I am working with Xcode 9 and using Cocoa framework throws this error.
I have tried all possible ways but not able to resolved it.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110392/required-code-signature-missing-for-a-library

Comment: @Priya i have tried to delete derived data but its not working.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: set provisioning profile

Comment: is this label from a pod?

Comment: @SPatel is this related to this ? i have automatically managed provisioning profile.

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio yes : https://github.com/kirualex/KAProgressLabel

Comment: @HemantSolanki can you archive your project?

Comment: @SPatel Yes bro

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio i have added your code in pod file but it's not working for me.

Comment: @HemantSolanki this worked for me, maybe you have another issue... run `pod --version` to know which version you have

Comment: @HemantSolanki Basically its cocapods bug in 1.5, to resolve this you can downgrade your cocapods version. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if label is a lib in a pod, you probably are affected by a cocoapods bug; try to add this post_install in your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

I suggest you to remove all derived data and clean from xcode.
Then, re-install pods with `pod install`

Answer (score 2):

I had to combine the above two excellent answers (Podfile modification and cocoa pod version 1.4.0) plus another Podfile modification from another thread

My Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.new_shell_script_build_phase.shell_script = "mkdir -p $PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/#{target.name}"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'] = '$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR'
            config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
            config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
        end
    end
end
```

then

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0
```

Works for me on Xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with Cocoapod version 1.5.0
If you are using this you will get this error.

To remove your current version you could just run:

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

you can install a specific version of cocoa pods via the following command:

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0

Remove Podlock file before the update.

Comment: This was the missing part for me, when combined with Rico's answer it works.